# Changing Last Name "required" attribute in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

In SugarCRM, person name consist of First Name and Last Name and Last Name is a required field ( First Name optional ) . How can remove required attribute from last_name and make First Name as required instead? Will it work without ripple effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the given link for answer,

http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/f6/how-change-last-name-required-user-module-69943/